# How to rotate an item frame with a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to reset the rotation of an item inside an item frame (in an exact position/coordinates) using a command.
I was thinking about using [`replaceitem`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/replaceitem), but it says in that page:

> The inventory of an item frame can only be changed with /data.

So how can I do that with [`data`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/data), or any other alternative?

(Latest release: 1.14.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki was actually wrong about `/replaceitem` not working for item frames, it's even mentioned in the history, but wasn't changed in the main article so far. I changed that now.

But that still doesn't help you, because you can't rotate the item with that, because the rotation is not a property of the item, but of the frame. It's documented here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame#Entity_data ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Item_Frame&oldid=1378554#Entity_data))

To reset the rotation of an item, you can just use this command:

```
/data merge entity @e[type=item_frame,sort=nearest,limit=1] {ItemRotation:0}
```

To set it to 45°: `{ItemRotation:1}`
This goes up to `7`, which is 45° rotated to the left from the default.

To rotate an item frame item relative to the current rotation, you first need to store the rotation in a scoreboard, then change that scoreboard and then put the value back into the item frame rotation NBT:

```
/scoreboard objectives add rotation dummy
/execute as @e[type=item_frame] store result score @s rotation run data get entity @s ItemRotation
/scoreboard players add @e[type=item_frame] rotation 1
/execute as @e[type=item_frame] store result entity @s ItemRotation byte run scoreboard players get @s rotation
```

This rotates the item in every item frame by 45°. I'm pretty sure it wraps around from 8 to 0, but I didn't test it.